Human chasing an alien egg/bomb, bad alien running/chasing the same
Seen it around 1990s.
Include lots of chasing sequences.
One guy/hero is assigned to protect the egg, or diffuse the egg bomb. The hero is well trained and is assigned to the mission. He hunts for egg/bomb and he seems to be teleported from a different location. The villain alien tries to explode or capture the bomb. Aliens are found living in secrecy as normal humans.
I think the egg is born to an alien and human. Or it is a bomb. Don't remember it clearly.
Movie language is English. Movie begins with hero training at a remote location. He is contacted by some authority and asked to work on a mission. He seems to be on a vacation and is forced to work on the mission. He is teleported to a city and has no choice but to work on the mission.
